# Go to TOP and Search button don't respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I have a problem on my site that I've been debugging for several day's, but I'm somehow stuck where to look for a solution. On [my website](https://www.uisge-beatha.eu/reageer) when scrolling down past the fold a "arrow up" button should appear but it doesn't. If you click the magnifier, the part below the navigation bar should shift down and a search bar has to appear, but it doesn't.

These functionalities rely on two jQuery scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

For the mentioned effects the magnific js is used:

```
<script  src="{static_url}/tpl-buddy-011/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

Initialization is put together in a init-script

```
/*
         * Search 
        ---------------------------------------------------- */
        $('.search-trigger').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
            $('section.mobile-navigation').hide();
            $('.mobile-nav-trigger').removeClass('active');
            $('body').toggleClass('show-search');
            $('.search-input input[type="text"]').focus();
        });
/* 
         * Menu for Mobile
        ---------------------------------------------------- */ 
        $('.mobile-nav-trigger').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').removeClass('show-search');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('section.mobile-navigation').slideToggle('fast');
        });

        $(".totoplink a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top -88
            }, 800);
        });
```

A snippet from the html-code for the search-bar and the "go to top":

```
{* Main navigation *}
            <nav class="pull-right">
              {Navigator loadprops='0' template='buddy011-navigation' number_of_levels='3'}
            </nav>
            <div class="search-wrapper">
              <a href="#" class="search-trigger">{svg use="search"}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>


    <div class="wrapper">
    {* mobile navigation *}
      <section class="mobile-navigation">
        {Navigator loadprops='0' template='buddy011-navigation-mobile'  number_of_levels="3"}
      </section>

      {* Search *}
        <section class="search-input">
          {Search search_method="post" formtemplate='buddy011-searchform' resultpage="{if isset($search_page)}{$search_page}{/if}"}
        </section>
```

I can put the css, however that's quit a lot of code, and that will not make the post much clearer. The question I have, is how I can debug the site to find the missing behavior of the buttons?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using such archaic, and out-of-date jQuery versions?

Answer (score 0):

Found it because of the answer given by Mukesh. Noticed an error related to FlexSlider (which is no longer in place), however that error was causing the non-function.

Answer (score 0):

Once ran into the same type of problem and after a long investigation figured out a change in the order of loading js-files was causing the issue.